# How to refresh data while saving in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to refresh my data while clicking save button. I am using a datagridview but it won't refresh automatically. How can I code it?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tblproduct (product, Supplierprice, Projectprice) VALUES (@product, @Supplierprice, @Projectprice)"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

    'parameters()

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", txtproductname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplierprice", txtsupprice.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projectprice", txtproprice.Text)

    Try
        con.Open()
        If MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure To Save This?", "SAVE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Successfully Saved")

            End If
        End If
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()

    End Try

    Refresh()

    Hide()

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you read about that `Refresh` method to see what it actually does? You're not the first person to assume that it magically knows what data you want to retrieve and display and then not bother to research when it doesn't do that.  All it does is redraw the form on the screen.  It knows nothing about your database.  If you want to retrieve data, you have to write code to retrieve data.

Comment: That said, why would you want to retrieve data that you just inserted.  You already have the data.  Why do you need to retrieve it again?  What you should do - what the many people who who make this same mistake should do - is add the data to the `DataTable` that is bound to the `DataGridView` first, so the grid is already updated, then save the changes from the `DataTable` to the database using a data adapter.

Comment: `i am using datagridview but it won't refresh automatically`, could you please add the code you are using that shows up in this `datagridview`? All you honestly need to do is call the code again after the insert happens, but you may not have that code in a separate method you could call...

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it.

First create a class.

```
Public Class Product
Public Sub New(productName As String, supplierPrice As String, projectPrice As String)
    Me.ProductName = productName
    Me.SupplierPrice = supplierPrice
    Me.ProjectPrice = projectPrice
End Sub

Public Property ProductName As String

Public Property SupplierPrice As String

Public Property ProjectPrice As String

End Class
```

Declare a BindingList of the class and use that as the datasource. When adding an item, just add to the BindingList. The grid will automatically be refreshed.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Products As New BindingList(Of Product)

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    dgvProducts.DataSource = Products
End Sub

Private Sub bnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnAdd.Click
    Dim item As Product = New Product(tbProductName.Text, tbSupplierPrice.Text, tbProjectPrice.Text)

    If MessageBox.Show($"Are You Sure To Save the product : {item.ProductName}?", "SAVE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        SaveProduct(item)
        Products.Add(item)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SaveProduct(item As Product)
    'Add database insert code
End Sub

End Class
```